# cut-off rates for error correcting codes

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory

I have also asked this at the EE stack but got no answer.

---

Before 1990 or so, communications link designers used the concept of computational cut-off rates (instead of Shannon capacity) to estimate what could or could not be done in a dig-com channel. This idea goes back to Wozencraft and later promoted by Massey.

My question is: in the age of turbo codes, what, if any use and/or meaning is there for the computational cut-off rate beyond its very original meaning, namely, it represents nothing more than the maximum rate that a sequential decoder can handle in finite time?

Comment: It seems that while Shannon provides the theoretical limit - not related to the type an the practical implementation, the "computational" relates more to the practical implementation - as result it seems that Shannon is a better measure to understand limitation as you start a design and the "computational" as the design progress into an actual architecture.

Comment: Even though I do not follow the latest developments in coding theory, I would say that the (computational) cut-off rate is not very relevant nowadays. Apart from turbo, we now have LDPC and polar codes (the latter are the first codes proven to achieve Shannon capacity), all of them achieving rates extremely close to Shannon capacity, which renders the cut-off rate a loose estimate of the maximum (and practically) achievable rates.